# Deploying Nuxt 3 on Azure (SSR)

Tags: azure, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

So I am trying to deploy my nuxt3 app but I am not exactly sure what *path* to upload from?

This is how my workflow looks like, so what should be the correct path ?

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
           ls -la .output/server

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .
          if-no-files-found: warn
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I am trying to deploy my nuxt3 app but I am not exactly sure what *path* to upload from?

You can just mention `.` as path. It will process all the files while deploying.

*I have created a simple nuxtjs application and deployed to Azure App Service.*

**Steps I followed:**

-Create nuxtjs application.

[image]

[image]

- Deploying the nuxtjs app to Azure web app using GitHub actions:
- I have deployed manually through `Azure App Service=>Deployment Center=> Select "GitHub" as *Source*` and sign in with github credentials.

[image]

**My workflow:**

Below is the automatically generated workflow:

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - <Web_App_Name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<Web_App_Name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_FD95XXXXXXXXX }}
          package: .
```

***Deployment Status:***

[image]

[image]

***Portal:***

[image]

Comment: Hi @Pravallika-KV, is this app configured for linux or windows? Can you share what your wwwroot directory tree looks like?